# Join a column showing sum of 2 data together

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate

```
SELECT o.ProductID ,
       p.ProductName ,
       o.unitprice AS UnitCost ,
       sum(o.Quantity) AS TotalUnitsSold ,
       (sum(o.Quantity)*o.unitprice) AS FinalCost
FROM OrderDetails o
JOIN Products p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY o.ProductID ,
         p.ProductName ,
         o.unitprice
ORDER BY 1
```

I want one more column aside of Final Cost which gives total of Products,
in short for chai it should be `2505.60+11772.00`

[image: sql output]

EXPECTED o/p

```
ProductID    ProductName    UnitCost    TotalUnitsSold    FinalCost       Total
1                Chai            14.40        174           2505.60          14277.60
1                Chai            18.00        654           11772.00         Null
```

Comment: How do you decide which of the rows gets `NULL`?

Comment: it can either be null or the same value like in the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a windowed function, it will give total for all rows:

```
SELECT  T.ProductID
,       T.ProductName
,       T.UnitCost
,       T.TotalUnitsSold
,       T.FinalCost
,       SUM(T.FinalCost) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID) AS Total
FROM    (
            SELECT o.ProductID ,
                   p.ProductName ,
                   o.unitprice AS UnitCost ,
                   sum(o.Quantity) AS TotalUnitsSold ,
                   (sum(o.Quantity)*o.unitprice) AS FinalCost
            FROM OrderDetails o
            JOIN Products p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
            GROUP BY o.ProductID ,
                     p.ProductName ,
                     o.unitprice
        ) AS T
ORDER BY 1
```